# Using pipes in nautilus-actions

Tags: nautilus-actions

I don't know if this is a valid question, I want to make links from selected files in nautilus and move the link files to the desktop, but piping commands doesn't work.
My combination in "Path" field on "Command" tab is:

```
link %B "Link to "%B | mv * ~/Desktop
```

I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Can you explain more what do you want to do? You cannot create link ‘%B’ to ‘%B’.

Comment: True, i make link from %B to "Link to "%B

Comment: I'm still looking for a way to chain commands in an action please reply if you found one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why somebody didn't say: "Don't ask stupid questions again", because:

My combination in "Path" field on "Command" tab should be:

```
link %B /home/<username>/Desktop/"Link to "%B
```

But, for a reason unknown to me, `link` command only accepts one file and not directories. So i changed the command in "Path" field to:

```
ln --symbolic %F /home/<username>/Desktop/
```

And it works like a charm.

And apparently i can not use pipes in "nautilus-actions".